# Transmitted audio coming out through my speaker

Tags: rfi, kenwood, microphone, audio, speaker

I have a Kenwood TS590 HF transceiver. When I am transmitting and speaking into the microphone, I can hear my audio slightly coming out of my speaker connected to the radio (SP-23), or headphones if used instead. The audio is intelligible and isn't distorted.

What is causing this? , and what would be a way to solve it? It didn't happen with my previous radio. I have tried different microphones so it's not a microphone issue.

It's hardly an RFI issue either. I have also an RF choke connected to the output of my radio and also at the input to my antenna. This is not affecting my transmitted audio on the receiving end. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is coming out through the speaker connected to the 590, the SP-23.. or when I use headphones, it comes out through the headphones too

Comment: @rclocher3 I did edit my comment. No, the audio is intelligible, so i guess after the audio amplifier stage in the radio before the other stages, it's getting out.. strange though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manual, on page 56 says:

**TX monitor** allows you to monitor the on-going transmission sound. This is convenient when you want to check the modulation sound quality of the transmission. In FSK mode, you can monitor the FSK  signal that the transceiver is transmitting.

1 Press and hold [PWR (TX MONI)].
• The current TX monitor setting appears on the sub-display.

2 Turn the MULTI/CH control to select the monitor sound level from “oFF”, and “1” to “9”.

3 Press [CLR] to store the selected TX monitor level.

Comment: omg.. I feel silly now. Thanks alot for this. I had no idea that was a feature. The TS 590 is full of different configurable options which I am still learning about. Thanks.

Comment: @Engineer999 That wasn't a silly question. :-)

Comment: In telephony this is often referred to as "sidetone".